# PL/SQL UTL_FILE package read from csv and load values into a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

If I have a CSV file like this:

[image]

How can I read this with `UTL_FILE` package and load the values into one table which have columns: `ItemIdentifier, SoldOnWeb, SoldInTheShop`?

Comment: That's not a CSV-File, it's a screenshot. Please provide content of CSV file as formatted text.

Comment: Can you copy some real data from de CSV file?
are there 2 files or only 1 file?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, as CSV files can be edited with MS Excel, I'd suggest you to rearrange the file and uniform it. The way it is now, it contains different headings and - to make it worse - they don't "match" (the same column contains `itemidentifier` and `soldintheshop` values; the same goes for the next column).

Add yet another column which would explain what the "sold..." column represents. Finally, you'd have something like this:

```
itemidentifier   amount   location
--------------   ------   -------------
1                10       soldOnWeb
2                7        soldOnWeb
3                5        soldOnweb
1                7        soldInTheShop
2                3        soldInTheShop
```

Doing so, it is a simple task to insert every value where it belongs.

---

Otherwise, can it be done in PL/SQL? Probably. Will it be difficult? Probably, as you have to "remember" what you're selecting in each row and - according to that - insert values into appropriate columns in the table.

You know how it goes ... garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this is the way I will got the file. It was only a sample, but the original file will contain more rows and types and the data is sensitive to changes, so I would not rearrange that, but maybe I will seperate the file by types and create a new csv file for each of them.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd say that - whatever you do - you should **strongly try** to uniform files and data you'll be receiving. Otherwise, expect a lot of manual job which will take a lot of time with questionable outcome. People who send (prepare) files will probably not be happy as they will all have to use the same format (and when you're *constrained*, you kind of *suffer*), but for your own sake, try to do it properly.